# codova android inapp browser with _blank option is giving cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cors, whitelist

When i tried to open inapp browser with url(#/app/payumoney) like below

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('#/app/payumoney', '_blank', options)
        .then(function(event) {
            console.log("success "+JSON.stringify(event));
        })
        .catch(function(event) {
            console.log("error "+event);
        });
```

It is throwing the error attached in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE2K2.png).

I'm using cordova-android version 5.1.1 and installed cordova whitelist plugin as well

please some one help me out

Comment: have you added `<access origin="*" />` in config.xml ?

Comment: yes we have added the access origin config

Comment: Adding <access origin="*" /> has a security concern and is not recommended by Cordova community. Refer Link here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/ because many websites may automatically redirect from their home page to some other url which you didn't expect to get open from your app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding below meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;" >
```

Refer [ContentSecurityPolicyDocumentation](http://content-security-policy.com/) for more information on this.
Also make sure your url '#/app/payumoney' gets open in the browser of your device and then accordingly whitelist your url in config.xml from [WhitelistDocumentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/).